# How to add multiple files by drag n drop also by click with upload progress bar

Tags: javascript, angular

I have to build a custom upload with multiple file upload support with progress bar, I have done the design part. Only thing I cant find is multiple file upload with drag n drop and progress bar. Please help I have attached the progress sample image.

```
<div>
  <input type="file" id="file" multiple 
      (change)="getFileDetails($event)">
</div>
<div *ngFor="let file of myFiles">
  <div>{{file.name}} - {{file.type}} - {{file.size}}</div> 
</div>

myFiles:string [] = [];
  sMsg:string = '';

  ngOnInit () {  }

  getFileDetails (e) {
    //console.log (e.target.files);
    for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) { 
      this.myFiles.push(e.target.files[i]);
    }
    console.log(this.myFiles)
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uhy6ic?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)[image]

Comment: That's not just file upload, but an *asynchronous file upload*, you would need a server to which you would send the file bytes, and calculate the number of bytes sent and show the progress.

Answer (score 0):

I use ng2-file-upload.  It's pretty clean and allows for progress bars, automatic uploads, drag and drop, custom upload headers.
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload

simplified example from my codebase

```
    const authHeader = { name: "authCode", value: this.sessionService.GetAuthCode() }; //authorization token
    this.uploader = new FileUploader({
        headers: [authHeader],
        url: <path-to-api-service>,
        parametersBeforeFiles: true,
        autoUpload: true
    });
    this.uploader.onCompleteAll = () => {
        //reload available files
    };
    this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: FileItem, response: string, status: number, headers: ParsedResponseHeaders) => {
        console.log("file completed", item, status, response, headers);
    };
```